# What is the best numerical integration method for evaluating probabilities from z scores.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gaussian-integral, simpsons-rule

I used Simpson's rule to calculate the area under a standard distribution where $z\gt1$.

This is the integral: $$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_1^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$

I decided to go as far as $z=4$ and to use $9$ points. So I used my calculator to find values for $z=1.0, 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3.0, 3.4, 3.8, 4.2$

Simpson's rule gave me a result of $0.1586$. Tables give a result of $0.1587$ so I'm pretty happy with this.

I am only familiar with Simpson's rule and the trapezoidal rule. I have heard of Gaussian quadrature and some other rules.

What is the most convenient/accurate/appropriate rule to use on a Gaussian/standard distribution ?

Comment: Why do you want to use numerical method to compute a constant? Do you have any parameters that vary?

Comment: @uranix I'm not sure what you mean. x varies.

Comment: I mean that the integral value is constant (it does not depend on any parameters). Just precompute it using WolframAlpha and you're done. Using numerical integration method is justified when you're dealing with unknown function of some form or have, for example, varying lower bound or scale parameter. To integrate Gaussian distribution I strongly advise using erf/erfc functions that any decent math library has.

Comment: @uranix Ok , but I'm showing students how to calculate probabilities from z-values on paper. They and I have already ''mastered'' looking the values up :)